# How can I prove that $g\cdot H \cdot g^{-1}$ is also finite and has the same number of elements that $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ a group and  $H$ is a finite  subgroup  of $G$ also $\forall g \in G$  the set $g\cdot H \cdot g^{-1}=\{ g\cdot h \cdot g^{-1} : h\in H\}$, is a subgroup of $G$.

Prove that $g\cdot H \cdot g^{-1}$ is also finite and has the same number of elements that $H$?

If I try to prove it using a bijection between $H$ and $g\cdot H \cdot g^{-1}$  and . How do I have to use the hypothesis of "finite"?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You don't have to use finite condition actually.

Comment: How is finite a hypothesis here, seems like a conclusion to me.

Comment: I'm sorry... How can I use the fact of $H$ being finite?

Comment: If there's a bijection between two sets, either both are finite, or both are infinite. You don't need finiteness of $H$ for the "bijection" part, but you do for the finiteness of $gHg^{-1}$ (which is really a consequence of the "bijection" part).

Comment: By the way, you don't have to *suppose* that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup. This is automatic if $H$ is a subgroup. Proof: (1) Fix $g \in G$. Then $e = geg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$. So $gHg^{-1}$ is not empty. (2) Suppose $a,b \in gHg^{-1}$. So $a=gh_1g^{-1}$ and $b = gh_2g^{-1}$. Then $ab = (gh_1 g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1}) = gh_1 h_2 g^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$. (3) Suppose $a \in gHg^{-1}$. Then $a = ghg^{-1}$, so $a^{-1} = (ghg^{-1})^{-1} = gh^{-1}g^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$. These three observations show that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation by an element is an automorphism, the reciprocal of $\;x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ being $\;x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bijection between two sets, then they have the same cardinality (the same "number of elements"), so if you have a bijection between $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ and $H$ is finite, then $gHg^{-1}$ is finite too. (So that's how you use the finiteness of $H$.)

For the bijection you can use $f: H \to gHg^{-1}$ defined by $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$.

Surjectivity is immediate and injectivity follows from the existence of inverses in $H$ and closure.